# Не работает removeAttribute

Tags: javascript

Почему не удается удалить disabled, через removeAttribute?

```js
let summ = document.querySelector('.choose-sum');
summ.addEventListener('click', function() {
  summ.getAttribute('disabled');
  summ.removeAttribute('disabled');
});
```

```html
<div>
  <label for="sum">Сумма</label>
  <input disabled class="choose-sum" id="sum" type="text">
  <label for="percent">Процент</label>
  <input class="choose-percent" id="percent" type="text">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Атрибут `disabled` делает поле ввода неактивным, в том числе не срабатывают и клики на него.

То есть проблема заключается в том, что не срабатывает сам обработчик клика, а не метод `removeAttribute` внутри него.

Следовательно для решения нужно чтобы клик был по какому-либо еще элементу, например по кнопке "активировать" либо по какому-то элементу поверх инпута.